# Cant explicitly set dockerhub URI when doing docker login, or push will fail

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have some code that takes in a container registry URI, username, and password and then performs a `docker login`, `docker build` and `docker push`. Script works fine when using container registries other than dockerhub. When using dockerhub though, it fails to push.

`docker login docker.io/mydh/myrepo -u myusername -p mypassword`

`docker build . -t docker.io/mydh/myrepo:abc`

`docker push docker.io/mydh/myrepo:abc`

**denied: requested access to the resource is denied**

I get the denied error, even though I get a **Login Succeeded** message upon login. If I instead login without specifying the URI, it works fine

`docker login -u myusername -p mypassword`

What's going on? Why can't I push when explicitly including the dockerhub URI?

Comment: The error message indicates that the login indeed succeeded (i.e., authentication was successful), but your user does not have the permissions to do the push (i.e., authorization failed). Did you verify that the user you are using to push does have the appropriate permissions in Docker Hub for the Docker ID? Also, it seems kind of odd that you include "docker.io" in the tag, as for images on Docker Hub, usually `<username_or_namespace>/<image_name>` should be sufficient. See the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/).

Answer (score 0):

The options should be before the server.

```
docker login [OPTIONS] [SERVER]
```

In your case

```
docker login -u myusername -p mypassword docker.io/mydh/myrepo
```

[image]

Comment: I'm able to login successfully with the commands I had. The push just fails after.